# CSS inheritance issue

Tags: css, inheritance

I have one stylesheet (layout.css) that imports the following CSS at the top of the style sheet:

```
@import "reset.css";
@import "typography.css";
@import "forms.css";
@import "fonts/fonts.css";
@import "tablecloth.css";
```

Everything seems to be in order apart from that blasted typography style sheet. What I mean by that is when I apply a style to, say, a paragraph, the only styles applied to it are taken from the tyopgraphy style sheet.

Example:

Applied in layout.css:

```
#three-col-container #right-col.filter p.more { color: #ff0000; font-size: 1.2em; }
```

What Inspector is telling me is applied (these styles are included in the typography style sheet):

```
p { font-size: 1em; color: #444; }
```

I've never came across this sort of inheritance issue. The other style sheets are working as expected.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post this somewhere so I can see the actual code?

Comment: So you're saying that if you remove that line from typography.css, the line from layout.css starts working?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious; does the `<p>` in question really have a class of `more`, and is it really a descendent of the element with id `right-col` (with class `filter`), which in turn is a descendent of the element with id `three-col-container`?

Comment: Can you share a link to a page with that example?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `!important` flag on the end of the rule you want to override, before the semicolon.

This will make sure it's always applied, and so should override the inherited rule.

Comment: In general, `!important` is an - albeit useful - last resort. David should probably try to figure out what's actually going wrong first.

Comment: I would avoid !important as you will begin a constant battle over specificity.

Comment: It would at least solve the immediate problem, although I agree; if possible you should fix the actual problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

`#three-col-container #right-col.filter p.more` means:

Apply this style to paragraphs (`p`) which have the `more` class that are descendants of something which has the id `right-col` *and* class `filter` **that** is descendant of something with id `three-col-container`.

Is this right?

Are you sure that in the typography stylesheet the style rules don't have the `!important` flag at the end? Are you that the URL of that stylesheet is correct?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a specificity issue??

I found this awhile ago that's helpful when trying to determine css inheritance rules:

- Add **1** for each *element* (ex `p` and `a`) and *pseudo-element* (ex `:before` and `:after`);
- add **10** for each *attribute* (ex `[type=”text”]`),
  *class* and *pseudo-class* (ex `:link` or `:hover`;
- And add **100** for each *ID*;
- and add **1000** for an *inline style*.

So `#three-col-container #right-col.filter p.more` has 2 ID's, 2 classes and 1 element, so it has a weight of **221**.

Is it possible that there might be another rule that has a higher weight that's overriding your rule? Are there any other styles being applied other than those two? (Or even javascript applying inline rules?)

I try and use either Firebug or the Chrome/Safari Developer tools to try and figure out what rules are coming from where. Typically it'll give you the name of the css and the line the rule is on, the overridden rules will have a strikethrough. Once I figure out what rules are taking precedence I can raise or lower the weight of the rule to make it inherit properly.

Hopefully that helps!